# Using mysql LIMIT keyword to select data with inconsistent auto-incremented ids

Tags: mysql

i have over 1000 rows of data in a mysql table and i want to process theme 50 rows at a time using my java program.The program has so many deletions and insertions,i am not even sure the first record starts at 1.

When using mysql limit `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0, 10` should this be read as first 10 records and does  the incremented id feature in `LIMIT 0, 10`?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no surity to read first 10 record by following query

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0, 10
```

If you want to read first 10 record then use following query with `order by` clause like

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: What about the next ten?.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id LIMIT 10, 10`